# find functions that $f(m+k)=f(mk-n)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functional-equations

Find all functions from naturals excluding $0$ to reals that for a particular amount of $n$ we have:

$f(m+k)=f(mk-n):(mk>n , m,k,n \in \Bbb Z^+)$

by putting $k=1$ and $m>n$ we can see that the function is periodic with cycle of $n+1$.But I can't continue.

Comment: Are we to assume that $m,k,n \in \mathbb{N}$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$k=n+1$, using the (n+1)-periodicity then for all $m$, \begin{align} f(m) &= f(m+n+1)\\ & =f((m-1)(n+1) + 1) = f(1)
\end{align}