# Find all functions $f:\Bbb N\rightarrow \Bbb R $ such that: $f(m+k)=f(mk-n)$

Tags: functional-equations, arithmetic-functions

> Find all functions $f:\Bbb N\rightarrow \Bbb R $ such that for a given value $n\in \Bbb N$ , the following identity holds: $$f(m+k)=f(mk-n) ,m,k \in \Bbb N ,  mk>n$$

This problem has already been asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2385733/find-functions-that-fmk-fmk-n) . I tried to get more deep solutions using my reputation but failed,so I repeat it here.

Comment: what's wrong with the existing answer?

Comment: I don't get it,I need more explanation.

Comment: Let me know if you still need more clarification...

Comment: @Henrik I DID know it's duplicate! Don't you see my text??

Comment: I did. Wanting more explanation doesn't IMHO justify posting it again, it means you should post one or more comments on the answer(s) to the original question.

Comment: Firstly, I used bounty which didn't work.I think for an old question posting new comments doesn't draw enough attention

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly we show that the function must be periodic with period $n+1$.  We do this by picking appropriate values of $m$ and $k$.
For any $l \in \mathbb{N}$ we can set $m = n + l$ and $k = 1$, and observe from the relation that
 $$f(n + l + 1) = f(m + k) = f(mk - n) = f(l)$$
which indeed shows that $f$ must be periodic.

The second observation is that the function $f$ must be constant.
We see this by setting $m = l$ and $k = n+1$, so that 
$$f(l + n + 1) = f(m + k) = f(mk- n) = f\big(l(n+1) - n\big)$$
But since $f$ is ($n+1$)-periodic, we have $$f(l + n + 1) = f(l)$$
and
$$f\big(l(n+1) - n\big) = f\big(1\cdot(n+1) - n\big) = f(1)$$

So putting it together we find that for every $l \in \mathbb{N}$, $$f(l) = f(1)$$.

Thus $f$ must be constant.  Conversely, it's immediately clear that any constant function $f$ does satisfy the property in question.

Comment: Don't you think the last formula must be: $f(l)=f(1)$???

Comment: yes corrected thank you